# Is this set of functions countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to know if the set of functions $F=\{f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}:f(n)\neq 0 \text{ for finitely many n}\}$.

I haven't done a lot of progress really, but considering define the sets $A_n=\{f: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\ : f(n)=0\}$. If I could prove that each $A_n$ is countable then the union of them (which is the set $F$) would be countable, but how can I prove the countability of $A_n$?

Comment: You may want to instead let $A_n$ be the set of functions which are nonzero at exactly $n$ points.

Comment: Thank you!. But I'm still not sure how could I prove the countability of each of those sets.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First see how many functions do you have satisfying:

$f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) \neq 0$ for exactly one $n$. This can easily be seen to be countable. Then $f(n) \neq 0$ for finitely many $n$ is just $f(n) \neq 0$  for exactly 1 $n$ union $f(n) \neq 0$ for exactly 2 $n$ , union.....

Alternately, think of these functions as the " bi- infinite sequences" $(...,a_1,a_2,...)$ where all but finitely many $a_i's$ are zero.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see how can I prove that each $A_n$ is countable, even with the first one that is 'easily' countable. I find it intuitive but I can't find a way to define a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$, maybe considering the set $N_1$ of $n$'s for $A_1$ that make $f(n)\neq0$ and define $g_1:A_1 -> N_1$ by $g_1(f_n) = n$ being $f_n\in A_1$ such that $f_n(n)\neq 0$?, thus defining an injection into $N$ which implies that $card(A_1)<card(N)$?. But how can I prove the general case?. Maybe defining $g_2:A_2\to \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$?, and use that the product of countable sets is countable.

Comment: My above try is wrong, considering again seems that $g_2$ isn't injective.

Comment: @balaya: Think of these functions as bi infinite sequences. Let's say we first want to find how many possible functions are there with $a_0 \neq 0$ (and rest 0). There are $"\mathbb{Z}"$ many choices for $a_0$. Now with just one coordinate nonzero means any of $a_i's$ could be nonzero- but there are countably many coordinates. So you get $\mathbb{Z}$x$\mathbb{Z}$ many choices- which is countable. Similar arguments work for the next cases.